# Strikeout in fraction equation

Tags: fractions, strikeout

I am having trouble getting the strikeout to work in this equation. I'd appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried variations of the \sout            \[\frac{(x-2)\sout{(x+1)}}{x+1}=x-2\]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

For such purposes is package `cancel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{(x-2)\cancel{(x+1)}}{\cancel{x+1}} = x-2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I forgot on divisor. Corrected now.

Comment: The full code provided did not work however, shortened to this works. \[\frac{(x-2)\cancel{(x+1)}}{\cancel{x+1}} = x-2\]. Thanks

Comment: @tina, I do not understand your comment. What does not work? What error you receive? My solution (as it is) definitely works, so I wonder what you change in your test.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code (changed nothing) and put it into my document. When I save, if it doesn't work, I see the code; if it does work I see the formatted equation. When I removed the first three lines and the last line of your code - it did work I saw the equation you have screen clipped above. For some reason the system I use doesn't need? like? the begin/end code. I have experienced this issue in the past.   Thank you for helping you solved it anyway. :-)